# Extracting MNIST in tensorflow: zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back

Tags: python, tensorflow, zlib, mnist

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
```

When using MNIST from tensorflow, I got the following issue:

```
Extracting MNIST_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/tianqing/.conda/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py", line 229, 
in read_data_sets
    train_images = extract_images(f)
File "/home/tianqing/.conda/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py", line 53, in extract_images
magic = _read32(bytestream)
File "/home/tianqing/.conda/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py", line 35, in _read32
return numpy.frombuffer(bytestream.read(4), dtype=dt)[0]
File "/home/tianqing/.conda/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/gzip.py", line 274, in read
return self._buffer.read(size)
File "/home/tianqing/.conda/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/_compression.py", line 68, in readinto
data = self.read(len(byte_view))
File "/home/tianqing/.conda/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/gzip.py", line 469, in read
uncompress = self._decompressor.decompress(buf, size)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back
```

I found it is the zlib problem, but can't get any help in stack overflow. Is there any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you are having such problem but when I was learning this dataset I imported this way and it works.

```
In [1] # Import MINST data
       from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
       mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

       Extracting /tmp/data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
       Extracting /tmp/data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
       Extracting /tmp/data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
       Extracting /tmp/data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
```

Comment: Thank you.  I directly download MNIST dataset from Doc LeCun's homepage and it works. I think the default download of TensorFlow may suffer from some file failure in my computer